# adding signer digital signature to pdf using itext

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

Trying to add digital signature(.JKS file) to pdf by using below code. Problem is that when run the code using self signed digital certificate its working fine but when we run the code with signer digital certificate (verisign) its giving NullPointerException.

```
    KeyStore ks = null;
    PrivateKey key = null;
    Certificate[] chain = null;
    PdfStamper stp = null;
    PdfReader pdfreader = null;
    PdfSignatureAppearance sap = null;
    int numberPages = 0;
    ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());  
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(jksFile), jksPassword.toCharArray());
    String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
    key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, jksPassword.toCharArray());
    chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    pdfreader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
    numberPages = pdfreader.getNumberOfPages();
    stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(pdfreader, baosWithSign, '\0');
   stp.setEncryption(null, null, PdfWriter.AllowPrinting, PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS);
    sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
    sap.setCrypto(key, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
    sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(532, 50, 532 + 30, 50 + 30), numberPages, null);
    stp.close();
    baos.close();
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.getAppearance(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:395)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:902)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:847)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper.close(PdfStamper.java:175)
        at testjks.ConvertPDFtoByteArray.convertPDFToDigitalSigatureAndPassword(ConvertPDFtoByteArray.java:99)
        at testjks.ConvertPDFtoByteArray.main(ConvertPDFtoByteArray.java:115)
```

Even i tried with below but same error

```
sap.setCrypto(key, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.VERISIGN_SIGNED);
```

Can any one help, Why i am getting PrivateKey object and Certificate[] object as null, where as selfsigned digital certificate giving output. Is there any extra code required for signer digital certificate.

Comment: When I see my name (I am Lowagie) in your error messages, I know that you're using a very old version of iText. You are creating signatures that are no longer accepted because the signing technology you are using is deprecated. I'm pretty sure that your customer wants state-of-the-art (PAdES compliant) signatures, which means that you have to upgrade to a more recent version of iText. You care currently using a version that dates from 2009 and digital signatures technology has evolved significantly since that date.

Comment: Thanks Lowagie for reply, Using jks file how to make signed (verisinged) pdf using latest version

Comment: the signature to be visible in last page of page (sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(532, 50, 532 + 30, 50 + 30), numberPages, null))

Comment: Did you read the [eBook](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html)? Just register, download it, and read it. You'll learn how to use a key from a CA. It would really surprise me if you'd sign using a file from Verisign. I would expect that they make you work with a token or an HSM.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie is right of course: if you have to use iText 2.1.7 (or some 4.2 variation) for some reason, do create the signature container externally in a way to adhere to currently accepted signature schemes and policies, and then inject that externally created signature container into the PDF. And before doing so, learn enough about electronic signature related legislation and standards, cryptography, and PDF to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Read [Are PDF Signatures shattered?](http://itextpdf.com/blog/are-pdf-signatures-shattered) if you want to inform your customer why you should not use versions older than iText 5.4 to digitally sign a document. If you don't tell your customer, and your customer finds out that you created signatures that are insecure, you might not get paid for your work (or even get sued).